# How to print an Extjs Window

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have a window consisting of a FormPanel with a gridPanel in it. I click on the grid to populate the data into to form. I would then like to be able to print out the form.

Printing using window.print() does not print correctly, I have tried several solutions but I am unable to get them working.

Is there an easy way to do this please.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to send the data to fpdf and print it that way.

Thanks